# Count occurrences of subsequence in all substrings of string

Tags: string, algorithm, time-complexity, sequence, dynamic-programming

I want to write an algorithm that counts the total number of (disjoint) occurrences of a subsequence of characters within all substrings of a string. An example is below.

String: "jabcohnnyjohnny"

Subsequence: "johnny"

Substrings containing subsequence:

```
jabcohnny
jabcohnnyj
jabcohnnyjo
jabcohnnyjoh
jabcohnnyjohn
jabcohnnyjohnn
jabcohnnyjohnny (2x)
abcohnnyjohnny
bcohnnyjohnny
cohnnyjohnny
ohnnyjohnny
hnnyjohnny
nnyjohnny
nyjohnny
yjohnny
johnny
```

Answer: 17

Checking every possible substring through brute force is simple enough, but I want a more efficient solution. I'm trying to figure out an algorithm with better than O(N^2) time complexity, where N length of the string. We can assume that the length of the subsequence is small and constant, so that's not an issue for time complexity.

I notice that the brute force method of iterating through every possible substring repeats a lot of work. For example, substrings 1-6 in the example all count the same instance of the subsequence.

I've tried working out a solution using dynamic programming, based on the similar problem of [finding the number of occurrences of a subsequence in a string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-times-string-occurs-given-string/). Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to account for all substrings, rather than just the ones starting from the beginning of the string.

I also get the notion that this problem can be solved using a two-pointer or sliding window method, but I haven't been able to make much progress with these, either.

Comment: Could [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm) be applicable?

Comment: If the string is "aabc" and the subsequence is "abc", is the answer 2 or 3? In other words, do the subsequences in a subarray have to be disjoint, or can they overlap?

Comment: How about the string "ababcc" and subsequence "abc"?

Comment: @Neil It looks like this algorithm deals with counting substrings, rather than subsequences, within strings.

Comment: @user3386109 The subsequences must be disjoint. The solution to both of your examples would be 1.

Comment: Minor correction: the brute force approach would have `O(N^2 * M)` complexity, where `M` = length of the substring you're trying to find.

Comment: I'd start by finding the start (Si) and end (Ei) index of every occurrence of the subsequence in the string. Assuming  the first two subsequences don't overlap (i.e. E1 < S2), every subarray that includes S1 and E1 but doesn't include E2 has one occurrence of the subsequence. Every subarray that includes both S1 and E2 has two occurrences. And every subarray that doesn't include S1, but does include S2 and E2 has one occurrence.

Comment: In your example, S1=0, E1=8, S2=9, E2=14
So there are E2-E1 = 6 substrings that include S1 and E1, but not E2.
There's one substring that includes S1 and E2 (x2).
There are S2-S1 = 9 substrings that don't include S1, but do include S2 and E2.
Therefore, the total is 6+2+9 = 17.

Comment: @user3386109 Hmm this is a good starting point. But we can't conclude that a sequence exists in a substring just because we see its start and end characters. For example, the start and end of the sequence "abcd" exist in the string "aeed", but it clearly does not contain the whole sequence.

Comment: Right, you need to find each instance of the subsequence in the string, and record the start and end index for the instance. Given the full list of start and end indexes, the problem seems more manageable to me. OTOH, enumerating all of the subsequences is harder than just finding the number of the subsequences. In my first example ("aabc") there are two instances. In the second example "ababcc", there are 6: `ab--c-`, `ab---c`, `a--bc-`, `a--b-c`, `--abc-`, `--ab-c`. But `ab--c-` and `a--bc-` have identical start and end, so they only count as 1. Same for `ab---c` and `a--b-c`, so there are 4

Comment: In short, you need to find all of the start/end pairs. The other characters of the subsequence must exist, and must be in the correct order, but the only information you need about each subsequence is the index of the first and last character.