# How can I find each subsequence in a string that can form a specific target?

Tags: string, algorithm, search

For example, if I'm given a string `s` = `"xTARGxxxxTARxETxxxxGET"`, I want to iterate through the string and store the pairs `1, 14` and `9, 21` which represent the start and end indices of the subsequences in `s`, `"TARGxxxxTARxET"` and `"TARxETxxxxGET"`, from which `"TARGET"` can be formed by deleting zero or more characters.

I know that I can iterate through every time I reach a `'T'`, but I'm looking for a more efficient solution.

Comment: Regexp `(?=(T.*?A.*?R.*?G.*?E.*?T))` is an easy solution, though it is likely that more efficient ones exist.

Comment: I'd use 5 lists, one for each letter after the first `T`. An element in a list is the start index. So the `G` list contains the start index of all subsequences that are looking for a `G`. When a `G` is found, the elements in the `G` list are moved to the `E` list.

Comment: You can simply check for subsequence in between every pair of `T`'s.

Comment: Will the string always be `TARGET` or could it be anything? Why is `TARGxxxxTARxETxxxx` not a valid substring as it has the subsequence `TARGET`? Is it that we need to stop at the last character of the subsequence in the substring?

Comment: @nice_dev [A higher level version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75845603)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using two pointers, one to iterate over the string s and another to iterate over the string "TARGET". This will allow you to check for the subsequences in a single pass through the input string. Here's a Python function to find the desired subsequences:

```py
def find_target_subsequences(s):
    target = "TARGET"
    target_length = len(target)
    subsequences = []
    
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        start = None
        target_idx = 0
        
        while i < len(s) and target_idx < target_length:
            if s[i] == target[target_idx]:
                if start is None:
                    start = i
                target_idx += 1
            i += 1
        
        if target_idx == target_length:
            subsequences.append((start, i - 1))
    
    return subsequences

s = "xTARGxxxxTARxETxxxxGET"
print(find_target_subsequences(s))
# Output: [(3, 15), (9, 22)]
```

This function initializes two pointers, i and target_idx, and iterates through the string s to find subsequences of "TARGET". The variable start stores the starting index of a valid subsequence. When the entire "TARGET" string has been matched (target_idx == target_length), the function adds the start and end indices of the subsequence to the subsequences list.

Comment: The output from your code is `[(1, 14)]`

Comment: This is pretty much the same as my current approach - it fails to account for overlaps (like in the example string).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the indices of each character in your target word into a dict (`defaultdict(list)`) and then starting from first character do a binary search using `bisect_left` and go through each character until end of target word.

Repeat this for each index of the starting character.

The complexity in the worst case is you are doing (number of starting character indices)*((n-1)*binary_searches).

Code not fully tested:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from bisect import bisect_left

def get_subs(s, t):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c in t:
            d[c].append(i)
    res = []
    done = False
    i = 0
    while i < len(d[t[0]]) and not done:
        v = d[t[0]][i]
        start_val = v
        j = 0
        while j + 1 < len(t):
            k = t[j + 1]
            if k == t[j]:
                v = v + 1
            pos = bisect_left(d[k], v)
            if pos == len(d[k]):
                done = True
                break
            end_val = d[k][pos]
            v = end_val
            j += 1
        if not done:
            res.append([start_val, end_val])
        i += 1
    return res
```

```py
print(get_subs("xTARGxxxxTARxETxxxxGET", "TARGET"))
print(get_subs("xTARGxxxxTARxETxxTARGxxxETRGAxxxTEGExxxxxGET", "TARGET"))
print(get_subs("TATTTTRGETTTT", "TTT"))
print(get_subs("aaaaaaaaaaaaa", "a"))
print(get_subs("aaaaaaaaaaaaa", "aa"))
print(get_subs("aaaaaaaaaaaaa", "ab"))
print(get_subs("tratratataratarararart", "art"))

[[1, 14], [9, 21]]
[[1, 14], [9, 25], [14, 25], [17, 25]]
[[0, 3], [2, 4], [3, 5], [4, 9], [5, 10], [9, 11], [10, 12]]
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6], [7, 7], [8, 8], [9, 9], [10, 10], [11, 11], [12, 12]]
[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9], [9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12]]
[]
[[2, 6], [5, 12], [7, 12], [9, 12], [11, 21], [13, 21], [15, 21], [17, 21], [19, 21]]
```

You can play with the code at https://replit.com/@somdude/SomeDude?v=1

Answer (score 0):

At each iteration, we need to determine whether we can extend the ongoing subsequence, or start a new one. In order to extend a subsequence, the following conditions should hold:

1. The subsequence length must be less than the `source`.
2. The current character must exist after the previous character in the `source`.
   In order to efficiently check condition #2, we maintain a list of indices for each character in the `source`, and also remember the last indices of the characters used in the subsequence so far. Since the list of indices is sorted by virtue of its construction, we can binary search for an index of the current character that is greater than the index of the previous character.

**Time Complexity:** In the worst case, the `source` has many repetitions of a single character, then binary search takes `O(log m)` time, where `m` is the length of the `source`. We do this for the length `n` of the `target`, giving us overall an `O(n log m)` algorithm.

Fully tested code that returns the minimum number of subsequences of `source` such that their concatenation equals `target`.

```
def shortest_way(source: str, target: str) -> int:
    def nxt_idx(c: str, k: int) -> int:
        if k == 0:
            return 0
        lo = used_ltr_idx.get(c, -1)
        prev_ch = target[k - 1]
        prev_ch_idx = ltr2idx[prev_ch][used_ltr_idx[prev_ch]]
        return bisect.bisect_left(ltr2idx[c], prev_ch_idx + 1, lo=lo + 1)

    ltr2idx: dict[str, list[int]] = defaultdict(list)
    for i, ch in enumerate(source):
        ltr2idx[ch].append(i)
    len_subseq, num_subseq = 0, 1
    used_ltr_idx: dict[str, int] = defaultdict(int)
    for i, ch in enumerate(target):
        if ch not in ltr2idx:
            return -1
        if len_subseq < len(source) and (j := nxt_idx(ch, i)) < len(ltr2idx[ch]):
            used_ltr_idx[ch] = j
            len_subseq += 1
        else:
            len_subseq = 1
            num_subseq += 1
            used_ltr_idx.clear()
            used_ltr_idx[ch] = 0

    return num_subseq
```

You can trivially modify it to return the indices of the subsequences.